# How do I pass the current working directory to a subshell in a different working directory?

Tags: linux, shell

I effectively just want to write:

```
/path/to/some/command .
```

but that command needs the working directory set so I'm trying to do:

```
(cd /path/to/some && command .)
```

but now `.` is `/path/to/some`.  How do I reference the current directory instead?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `/path/to/some/command /anotherpath` should work.

Comment: @Yves -- I don't know what `/anotherpath` is, I just want to pass the current directory

Comment: I find scripts that require cd'ing to their parent annoying. Why don't you instead make the script find out the location of itself like this: `HERE=$(dirname "$0")` (I assume it needs some sibling files so now it finds them under $HERE) so you can just call the script from any dir: `/absolute/or/relative/path/to/the/script .`

Comment: @VilleOikarinen -- The script I'm calling isn't under my control.  I completely agree that it's annoying :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the env variable `OLDPWD` to retrieve the previous working directory.

```
(cd /path/to/some && command "$OLDPWD")
```

Comment: Perfect, I knew there had to be something like this, thanks!